# Parse error: syntax error unexpected '$' (T_VARIABLE) expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: php, poo

Estoy probando el patrón singleton para crear la conexión con mi base de datos, esto es debido a que crear conexiones en cada archivo retrasa tiempo y resulta mejor utilizarlo, creo instancias llamando a la clase **`Dbconnect`** en otros archivos, pero me da error:

> Parse error: syntax error unexpected '$' (T_VARIABLE) expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Este es el codigo de mi conexión, tiene 3 funciones

```
<?php
  class ConnectDb {

  private static $instance = null;
  private $conn;
  
  private $host = 'localhost';
  private $dbname = 'seguridad';
  private $user = 'root';
  private $pass = '';
   

        private function __construct(){

        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};
        dbname={$this->dbname}", $this->user,$this->pass,
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
                                      }

  
        public static function getInstance(){
    
            if(!self::$instance){

            self::$instance = new ConnectDb();
                                }
   
            return self::$instance;
        }
  
 
         public function getConnection(){

            return $this->conn;
        }
}

?>
```

aqui me vota el error en este archivo especificamente en la linea numero 7, en esta estoy tratando de crear una instancia de la clase ConnectDB para posteriormente usarla en otros procesos

```
 <?php
include_once("objeto_reporte.php");
include_once("conexion.php");

class Manejo_reporte {

   $instance, ConnectDb::getInstance(); //I have the error here 
   $conn = $instance->getConnection();


    public function getReportePorFecha(){

        $matriz = array();
        $contador=0;
        $resultado = $this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM reportes_ficoa ORDER BY Fecha DESC");
            
            while($registro = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
                $reporte = new objeto_reporte();
                $reporte->setNombre($registro["Nombre"]);
                $reporte->setUbicacion($registro["Ubicacion"]);
                $reporte->setFecha($registro["Fecha"]);
                $matriz[$contador] = $reporte;
                $contador++;
            }
    return $matriz;
    }


    public function insertaReporte(objeto_reporte $reporte){

        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO reportes_ficoa (Nombre, Ubicacion, Fecha) VALUES (?,?,?) ");
        $arrParams=array( $reporte->getNombre() ,  $reporte->getUbicacion() , $reporte->getFecha() ); 
        $stmt->execute($arrParams);
        $this->conn = null;
        
        }

                    }
?>
```

Comment: en esa linea estoy tratando de crear una instancia de la clase ConnectDb y llamo sus funciones, estoy basandome en el patron singleton por eso la conexion tiene la funcion  getInstance() la cual crea la conexion y la otra funcion getConnection que la retorna, lo hice por que crear conexiones con mi bd en todos mis archivos consume tiempo

Comment: ya le edite la pregunta amigo, puse el codigo tal como me indica el portal

Answer (score 0):

Empecemos por el hecho de que esta línea que tienes aquí:

```
class Manejo_reporte
{
    $instance, ConnectDb::getInstance();
}
```

Es errónea por los siguientes aspectos:

- Parece que `$instance` es una propiedad de la clase, pero para eso debería tener un modificador de acceso declarado<sup>1</sup>
- Así como tampoco el hecho de que igualmente intentas declarar como propiedad de la clase a la clase y el acceso a su método estático.

Entonces, propongo los siguientes cambios:

- Dentro de la clase que usa la conexión, mueve los 2 elementos que causan conflicto a un método X
- Haz un retorno de la instancia accediendo al método `getConnection()` dentro de dicho método X
- Usa dicho método para componer la ejecución de la consulta
- Cuando hagas la instancia de la clase `Manejo_reporte` deberás indicar que el objeto también acceda al método recién creado.

Código de ejemplo:

```
 <?php

include_once 'Conexion.php';

class Manejo_reporte 
{
    
   public function esteMetodo()
   {
        $instance = ConnectDb::getInstance(); 
        return $instance->getConnection();
   }


    public function getReportePorFecha()
    {

        $consulta = $this->esteMetodo()->query("select * from tabla");
        $valores = $consulta->fetchAll();

        return $valores;
    }
}

$valor = new Manejo_reporte();
$valor->esteMetodo();
$valor->getReportePorFecha();
```

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Propiedades de clase](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php#language.oop5.properties)